# How to find top n matches from kNeighborsClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to search a vector from a set of sample vectors each with a label. I need to find the best `n` matches. I'm using `kNeighborsClassifier` for this.

```
nbrs = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='euclidean').fit(train_data_array, train_label)
yp = nbrs.predict(xt)
```

But the problem is that it returns only the top 1 result. I think on the basis of Euclidean distance I can get the top `n` matches but I'm not sure how to extract that information.

Comment: Btw, the paramater n_neighbors stands for the number of neighbors which will be used to compare with the input. That's why it is more favorable to pick an odd number instead of even numbers (default is 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`kneighbors()` method in KNeighborsClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors) which you can use.

It will return the indices of the training data (which you used in `fit()`), along with the distances which are closest to the points you supply in it.

Example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

# here I am taking a single point only
distances, indices = clf.kneighbors(X[[0]],  n_neighbors=2)

print(distances, indices)

#Output: array([[0., 0.]]), array([[17,  0]])
```

Here first output is the distances, and second is the indices of `X` which are nearest to `X[[0]]`